# Allow a user to connect to MySQL via MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to set up a connection to a database on my friend's laptop. I have his IP address and port number, but I can't connect to his machine and I think it's because he hasn't granted me permission. How does he grant me all privileges via the MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By below command-

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO your_name@'your_ip' identified by 'your_pass';
```

If you also want grant privileges, so that you can also assign rights then add `with grant option` at the end of sql.

from workbench gui you can do as per below-

go to `server > user and privileges > add account`

now you can choose options.

Comment: I knw this is via the Command Line Client, but we were just wondering if there was another way in the MySQL workbench?

Comment: I got an error saying: 
Can't find any matching row in the user table?

Comment: I have updated if you want to use GUI for user account creation..further if you are getting error by any method then share details....

Comment: Ah okay, I see now. Thank you

Comment: you may choose it as answer just clicking on green tick.

Comment: I was just waiting for it to let me... promise :)